# AttributeError at /customer/1/ 'customer' object has no attribute 'order_set'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset, attributeerror

I am trying to access the orders of each customer and i approached it this way:

```py
    def Customer(request, pk):
        Customer = customer.objects.get(id=pk)
        orders = Customer.order_set.all()
        order_count = orders.count()

        context = {
            'orders': orders,
            'customer': Customer,
            'order_count': order_count,
        }
        return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/customer.html', context)
```

on the youtube the man said that you can access the orders related to the customer by using the orders model name which in my case is 'order' and then add _set i did that and when i try to view the customer now i get this error: AttributeError at /customer/1/ 'customer' object has no attribute 'order_set'.

related models

```py
    class order(models.Model):
        STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        )
        order_head = models.ForeignKey(order_header, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        items = models.ForeignKey(item, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        Quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        total = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

        def __str__(self):
            return 'Order Customer: {self.order_head.Buyer}'.format(self=self)

    class customer(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

related view

```py
    def Customer(request, pk):
        Customer = customer.objects.get(id=pk)
        orders = Customer.order_set.all()
        order_count = orders.count()

        context = {
            'orders': orders,
            'customer': Customer,
            'order_count': order_count,
        }
        return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/customer.html', context)
```

related url

```
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', Customer, name="customer"),
```

related html

```
  {% for customer in customers %}
    <tr>
      <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'customer' customer.id %}">View</a></td>
      <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

I don't know if the query is wrong but in the youtube video, it's working.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue, kindly help if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `views.Customer` instead of just customer in `url.py` file.

`path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.Customer, name="customer")`

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    orders_count = orders.count()
    context = {'customer':customer, 'orders':orders, 'orders_count':orders_count}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
def Customer(request, pk):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
        orders = Customer.objects.all()
        myFilter = Customer(request.GET,queryset = orders)
        orders = myFilter.qs
        order_count = orders.count()

        context = {
            'orders': orders,
            'customer': customer,
            'order_count': order_count,
        }
        return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/customer.html', context)
```